# Puppeteer function doesnt run whats wrong?

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

```
    const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

    const init = async () => {
      const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false });
      const page = await browser.newPage();
      // login
      let login = async () => {
        console.log('login init');
        await page.goto(HOME_PAGE);
        await page.type($clientID, CLIENT_ID);
        await page.type($userName, USER_NAME);
        await page.type($password, PASSWORD);
        await page.click($submitBtn);
        await page.waitFor(WAIT_SEC);
        await page.goto(SCHEDULE_PAGE);
        console.log('login end');
      }

      // look for schedule
      let setStartDate = async () => {
        console.log('start init');
        await page.waitFor(3000);
        await page.click('#selfsched_startDate_dtInput', { clickCount: 3 });
        await page.keyboard.press('Backspace');
        await page.type($startDate, START_DATE);
        console.log('start end');
      }

      let setEndDate = async () => {
        console.log('end init');
        await page.click($endDate, { clickCount: 3 });
        await page.keyboard.press('Backspace');
        await page.type($endDate, END_DATE);
        await page.keyboard.press('Enter');
        console.log('end end');
      }

      let confirmSchedule = async () => {
        console.log('confirm init');
        await page.waitFor(WAIT_SEC);
        await page.click($confirmBtn);
        console.log('confirm end');
      }

      let steps = [
        login(),
        setStartDate(),
        setEndDate(),
        confirmSchedule()
      ];

      await Promise.all(steps);

      console.log('im finishing');
      browser.close();
    }

    init()
      .then(values => {
        console.log('success');
      })
      .catch(err => {

      });
```

Whenever my code gets to the `setStartDate` function nothing happens. 
I've added `console.log` messages but they're not coming in sequential order as i thought they would. I thought `Promise.all()` waits for everything in order..... also my knowledge in async / promises / await is not the greatest :) Thanks for the help

order of console logs im getting 

`login init
start init
end init
confirm init
login end`

Comment: Promise.all() will put the result array's elements in the same order, but the calls won't be sequential.

Comment: @ChrisG interesting. so how bad is this code?

Comment: Not too bad; just use something like `steps.forEach(step => await step)`

Comment: @ChrisG can you show me in code? im not sure what to do the in the body of the `forEach`

Comment: The example from my comment should work as-is. `await step` *is* the body.

Comment: ah i see what youre saying now too!!! thanks for the help!!

Comment: unfortunately `forEach` doesn't play well with `await` (it won't wait for promise resolution between iterations). You'd have to use an old-fashioned for loop and `await` inside that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I thought Promise.all() waits for everything in order

This is basically the opposite of what `Promise.all` does:

> There is no implied ordering in the execution of the array of Promises given. On some computers, they may be executed in parallel, or in some sense concurrently, while on others they may be executed serially. For this reason, **there must be no dependency in any Promise on the order of execution** of the Promises.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all

You should just `await` your functions in order:

```js
await login()
await setStartDate()
await setEndDate()
await confirmSchedule()
```

Comment: Yeah, `Promise.all` is useful when you don't care about the order of execution, only that all promises resolve successfully. As per MDN: "This method can be useful for aggregating the results of multiple promises."